# Bash function to produce variants of images at 2X and 3X resolutions

Tags: image, bash

I use ImageMagick to crop image, encapsulate the related code to functions.

Here is the code:

```
convertc2(){
  convert $1 -crop $2 "two.png"
}


converto3(){


  Delimeter="placeHolder"

  if [[ $2 == *"x"* ]]; then
    Delimeter="x"
  else
    Delimeter="X"
  fi

  First="${2%$Delimeter*}"
  Fourth="${2##*+}"
  Lhs="${2%%+*}"
  Rhs="${2#"$Lhs+"}"

  Second="${Lhs##*$Delimeter}"
  Third="${Rhs%+*}"

  One=$(echo "scale=0 ; $First * 1.5" | bc)
  One=${One%.*}
  Two=$(echo "$Second * 1.5" | bc)
  Two=${Two%.*}
  Three=$(echo "$Third * 1.5" | bc)
  Three=${Three%.*}
  Four=$(echo "$Fourth * 1.5" | bc)
  Four=${Four%.*}

  Final=$One"X"$Two"+"$Three"+"$Four

  echo $Final

  convert $1 -crop $Final "three.png"
}
```

Usage like this:

> ```
> convertc2 /Users/dengjiangzhou/Desktop/Simulator\ Screen\ Shot\ -\ iPhone\ 8\ -\ 2019-02-20\ at\ 14.39.02.png   300X300+0+0 
>
> converto3 /Users/dengjiangzhou/Desktop/Simulator\ Screen\ Shot\ -\ iPhone\ 8\ -\ 2019-02-20\ at\ 14.39.02.png    300X300+0+0
> ```

I need the image size of @2X and @3X. So the function `converto3`  use `convertc2` 's size and transform to its size.

```
Delimeter="placeHolder"
    
if [[ $2 == *"x"* ]]; then
    Delimeter="x"
else
    Delimeter="X"
fi
```

I really care about how to improve the above code. The "x" , I may type "X" or "x".

how to use this `"${2%$Delimeter*}"` insensitive?

And the calculation code in  `converto3()` is very ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Double-quote variables used as command line arguments

Instead of this:

> ```
> convert $1 -crop $2 "two.png"
> ```

Write like this:

```
convert "$1" -crop "$2" "two.png"
```

This is to protect from word splitting and glob expansion.

#### Double quote... naturally

This is hard to read and confusing:

> ```
> Final=$One"X"$Two"+"$Three"+"$Four
> ```

I suggest to write like this:

```
Final="${One}X$Two+$Three+$Four"
```

#### Use better variable names

It's really hard to make sense of a program that uses variable names like `First`, `Fourth`, `Second`, `Lhs`, that don't reveal their purpose.

Also, the convention is to use lowercase names, without capitalizing the first letters.

#### Chopping off characters case insensitively

Instead of detecting if the delimiter is `x` or `X` and storing it in a variable,
you could use the pattern `[xX]`, for example:

```
width=${spec%%[xX]*}
```

For example if you have `200x300` or `200X300` in `spec`, `width` becomes `200`.
(Do take note of the meaningful names.)

#### Floating point math in the shell

Unfortunately Bash doesn't do floating point math.
It would give you a syntax error if you tried to multiply something by `1.5`.
On the other hand, if you want to multiply by `1.5`, and you don't mind truncating decimal points (as is the case here), you could multiply by 3 and divide by 2.

That is, instead of this:

```
width=$(bc <<< "$width * 1.5")
```

You could write:

```
((width = width * 3 / 2))
```

#### Use here strings

Instead of `echo ... | cmd`, write `cmd <<< "..."`.

Comment: An alternative approach to matching `[xX]` would be to first downcase the string with expansion: `newSize="${2,,}"; width="${newSize%%x*}"` etc.